# ActionMethodSelectorAttribute + AllowHtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, filter, actionfilterattribute

I have an ActionMethodSelectorAttribute which i have the following line in:

```
 var req = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys.Any() ? controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Form : controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
```

However - this spews up when the form is posting HTML content.

Now - I do have AllowHtml on the InputModel being posted and the action itself does have ValidateInput(false)

I suspect the issue is that we haven't gotten that far down the pipeline yet

anyone know how to allow this for this filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AllowHtml` works only for the model binder IIRC and for `ValidateInput` is too soon because it is not yet certain which action will be executed. I was solving this issue few days ago and after some digging I found `ValidationUtility` in `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicValidationHelper`:

```
Func<NameValueCollection> formGetter;
Func<NameValueCollection> queryStringGetter;

ValidationUtility.GetUnvalidatedCollections(HttpContext.Current, out formGetter, out queryStringGetter);

var form = formGetter();
var queryString = queryStringGetter()
```

It's not really pretty, but it works :) Also note that ValidationUtility is hidden from intellisense.

Comment: and that is why SO kicks ass :D